# Chrome extension content script and document.ready event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, document-ready

My content-script defined to run on each and every page.
I encountered a problem with Facebook:
suppose I load "http://facebook.com", my content script runs and I can tell it because the event: $(document).ready() get fired. then, I press a link inside facebook (my profile page, or group I belong to), but the content script does not loaded again.

It's weired because the url is changing, so the content script should run again, isn't it?

Comment: Generally, content scripts don't need `document.ready`, because they run by default after the ready event has occurred.  This is ok in jQuery, because if `ready` has already happened, jQuery just fires the function instead of queueing it for later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the content of the page is reloaded not the whole entire page. The url changes doesn't mean that page is reloaded. You should listen to the change of the url itself. If the URl changes perform some code.

You can listen if the url of tab is changed using this method

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.url != null) { // check this condition, I didn't remember what is returned if the url didn't change.
    // your code
  }
});
```

I hope this helps you.