# Chrome Extensions - Script works only once, when I download a page the first time

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

The problem is that after it downloads the page the first time, it works, but if I click on "home" link, the script doesn't work anymore.

manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Facebook No Advs",
  "description": "This extension TRY to avoid advertisement from Facebook Home.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.11.0.min.js", "noAdvsScript.js"],
      "css": ["NoAdvsStyle.css"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Comment: Considering we have no idea what your content script does, it's hard to help.

Comment: Everything it does it works only once... eg. selectAnEl.css("bck", "red");

Comment: When you navigate the Facebook page, it does not really load a new page but changes its DOM, therefore the script does not get executed again. You need to listen to changes in DOM to react to elements that appear later.

Comment: Are you sure? Look, when you click on home the browser downloads the page from zero.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as I don't use Facebook, but it seems most likely. But I'm not putting this as answer.

Comment: In fact it's not that

Comment: Try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729712/chrome-extension-content-script-and-document-ready-event